# how can i pan / zoom on discrete axis

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to build a line chart using google chart api, I need to implement pan/zoom feature.

my Haxis is a discrete axis, here is my data

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Veriosn');
data.addColumn('number', 'Perf');
data.addRows([
['1.11', <?php echo $me  ?>],
['1.12', <?php echo $me  ?>],
['1.13', <?php echo $me  ?>],
['1.14', <?php echo $me  ?>],
['1.15', <?php echo $me  ?>],
['1.16', <?php echo $me  ?>],
['1.17', <?php echo $me  ?>]
]);
```

I used configuration option explorer: {}

```
var options = {
  explorer: { }
};
```

but this make no changes on my chart.
Can anyone help me with this feature in this case ?

Comment: Panning and zooming is only available on continuous axes (`'number'`, `'date'`, `'datetime'`, `'timeofday'` data types).  With a string-based major axis, you should be able to pan and zoom the vertical axis still.